# 3D image rotation in python

Tags: python, opencv, 3d, computer-vision, image-rotation

I have the following image I1. I did not capture it. I downloaded it from Google

[image]

I apply a known homography h to I1 to obtain the following image I2.

[image]

I want to assume that a camera has taken this above shot of I2. I have found the camera matrix of this "camera". Let this camera matrix be `k`. Now, I want to rotate this image I2 about the camera axis. According to the explanation in the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990350/python-rotate-image-about-camera-axis), I need to set the rotation matrix R and then perform `k*R*inv(k)*h` on image I1 to get the required rotated image I3.

I have been facing problems when I try to set this rotation matrix R. I have used [this method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle) to set the matrix R.

To test my code, I initially tried to rotate the image around the z-axis by 10 degrees but I wasn't getting the correct output.

My partial Python code:

```
theta_in_degrees = 10
theta_in_radians = theta_in_degrees*math.pi/180
ux=0.0 
uy=0.0 
uz=1.0 
vector_normalize_factor = math.sqrt(ux*ux+uy*uy+uz*uz)
ux=ux/vector_normalize_factor
uy=uy/vector_normalize_factor
uz=uz/vector_normalize_factor
print "ux*ux+uy*uy+uz*uz = ", ux*ux+uy*uy+uz*uz 
rotation_matrix = np.zeros([3,3])
c1 = math.cos(theta_in_radians)
c2 = 1-c1
s1 = math.sin(theta_in_radians)
rotation_matrix[0][0] = c1+ux*ux*c2
rotation_matrix[0][1] = ux*uy*c2-uz*s1
rotation_matrix[0][2] = ux*uz*c2+uy*s1
rotation_matrix[1][0] = uy*ux*c2+uz*s1
rotation_matrix[1][1] = c1+uy*uy*c2
rotation_matrix[1][2] = uy*uz*c2-ux*s1
rotation_matrix[2][0] = uz*ux*c2-uy*s1
rotation_matrix[2][1] = uz*uy*c2+ux*s1
rotation_matrix[2][2] = c1+uz*uz*c2
print "rotation_matrix = ", rotation_matrix
R = rotation_matrix
#Calculate homography H1 between reference top view and rotated frame
k_inv = np.linalg.inv(k)
Hi = k.dot(R)
Hii = k_inv.dot(h)
H1 = Hi.dot(Hii)
print "H1 = ", H1
im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, H1, (im_dst.shape[1],im_dst.shape[0]))
```

Here, `img_src` is the source of I1.

The result I got when I tried the above code is a black image with no part of the image visible. However, when I changed the value of `theta_in_degrees` to the following values, these were my outputs:

0.00003

[image]

0.00006

[image]

0.00009

[image]

Why is the rotation working only for such small values of `theta_in_degrees`? Also, the rotation visible in the images is not actually happening around the z-axis. Why isn't the image rotating about the z-axis? Where am I going wrong and how can I fix these issues?

h matrix:

```
[[  1.71025842e+00  -7.51761942e-01   1.02803446e+02]
 [ -2.98552735e-16   1.39232576e-01   1.62792482e+02]
 [ -1.13518150e-18  -2.27094753e-03   1.00000000e+00]]
```

k matrix:

```
[[  1.41009391e+09   0.00000000e+00   5.14000000e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   1.78412347e+02   1.17000000e+02]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]]
```

**Edit:**

After incorporating the suggestion by Toby Collins, I set the top left value of `k` to be the same as `k[1][1]`. When I now perform rotation about the z-axis, I get the correct rotated images for all values of `theta_in_degrees` from 0 to 360. However, when I try to rotate the image about the y-axis by changing the ux, uy and uz in the above code to the following, I get absurd rotation results:

```
ux=0.0 
uy=1.0 
uz=0.0
```

Some samples for different values of `theta_in_degrees` and the corresponding results for rotation about the y-axis are shown below:

-10

[image]

-40

[image]

-90

[image]

-110

[image]

Where am I still going wrong? Also, why is there such a huge drop in the length and width of successive yellow stripes in a rotated image? And why does a part of the image wrap around (for example, the results of rotation by -90 and -110 degrees)?

The second part of my question is this: The vector equation of my axis of rotation is `(320, 0, -10)+t(0, 1, 0)`. In order to use [this method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle), to calculate the rotation matrix, I need to define the `ux`, `uy` and `uz` of the axis of rotation such that `ux^2+uy^2+uz^2=1`. This would be straightforward if the rotation needs to be done around one of the coordinate axes (as I am currently doing for testing purposes). But how do I get these values of `ux`, `uy` and `uz` if the `t` in the vector equation of my rotation axis is variable? I am also open to suggestions regarding any other approaches to finding a suitable rotation matrix R such that the rotation happens around the axis I have mentioned (say, by x degrees).

Comment: The K matrix looks a little suspect with top left element being 1.41009391e+09

Comment: Try setting the top left element of K to 1.78412347e+02, so your camera has an aspect ratio of 1, and then run your code again. This will at least verify your code works for a given K matrix with an aspect ratio closer to real cameras.

Comment: If you want to rotate about the camera's Z axis (its optical axis) by an angle of theta your rotation matrix should be of the form R = [a,b,0;-b,a,0;0,0,1]. You should double check this.

Comment: I have verified that R is in fact in that form. I will experiment with the top left element of K as you suggested and get back to you. However, since you helped me with calculating the K matrix last time (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240239/python-calibrate-camera), do you have any ideas why I am getting such a huge value for the top left element of K? And if I add the flag to have an aspect ratio of 1, I no longer get a fixed value of the K matrix for different squares, as we discussed. Is there any way to fix both of these issues at once?

Comment: Yeah I see that. This just means that the results from an exact intrinsic calibration using your homography matrix h does not generate a solution with an aspect ratio close to 1. The way I see it you have two options: (1) You either need to change h so that it does generate a K matrix with an aspect ratio of 1, or (2) you need to find the best fitting K matrix using calibrateCamera with an aspect ratio of 1, using the method from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240239/python-calibrate-camera with a single large square covering the planar surface.

Comment: What's wrong with doing option 2? Do you really need your camera to exactly reproduce the image I2? It would mean you have a camera that approximates image I2, but is that not OK for your application?

Comment: I can also see from your h matrix that the element in row 3, column 1 is -1.13518150e-18. This is extremely small, which means the perspective distortion is basically zero. This could account for your strange K matrix, because when perspective distortion is zero, it means that it is impossible to calibrate focal length stably.

Comment: @TobyCollins Regarding the small value in row 3 column 1 of the h matrix, I am positive that this value is correct if I want the correct transformation. I have thoroughly verified this fact, and am confident that this is the correct h matrix I will have to work with.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion to change the top left element of the h matrix and set it equal to the fy value such that the aspect ratio becomes 1. While this shows the expected results for rotation about the z-axis, it is showing absurd results for rotation about the y-axis. I have been trying to figure out what I am doing wrong but I have been unsuccessful thus far. I have included the results in the edit to the question above. Any idea as to why this is happening? Is it due to changing the top left value of the h matrix to make the aspect ratio 1, or could it be something else?

Comment: I see you're still having some difficulty here. Let's step back a little. Can you precisely define what you want your full application to do? Why are you generating the correspondences in the way that you're doing? Is your application just meant to be orbiting a camera around a planar object? Or do you want to be rotating the camera on it's axis (without translating it), given a particular camera position?

Comment: Yes, the second thing is what I want to be able to do: I want to be rotating the camera on it's axis (without translating it), given a particular camera position. And I want to record the homography matrix `H'` for that particular rotation. This homography `H'` will map the original image `I1` to the rotated final image `I3`. I assume we get `I3` by rotating `I2` by `x` degrees about the camera axis. All of this is in accordance with this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47990350/python-rotate-image-about-camera-axis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difficulty you are having is that your homography matrix **h** does not  correspond well with a projection obtained with a *sensible* perspective camera. I think there is a simpler approach.

Fundamentally, you needed to be very clear about your technical goal, and separate this from your approach for solving it. Always do this whenever you tackle *any* vision problem.

### Technical goal

So let's be clear about the technical goal. You have a top-down image of a planar surface (also called a *rectified* view). Normally you would call this surface the *model*, defined on the plane z=0. You want to render this model. Specifically you want to do the following;

1. A virtual perspective camera is created that is looking at the model from a particular viewpoint. We define this model-to-camera rigid transform by **R**1, **t**1, with an intrinsic matrix **K**.
2. The camera is moved by rotating it about its centre of projection. Let's denote this rotation by **R**2.
3. The model is rendered using the view from 2. We will call this image *I2*

For simplicity I'm going to use T(**R**,**t**) to denote the 4x4 homogeneous rigid transform for some rotation **R** and translation **t**. The *model-to-camera* transform at stage 3 is therefore given by **T**=T(**R2**, (0,0,0)) x T(**R1**, **t**1).

### Rendering options

There are two good ways to create *I2*

1. **Use a rendering engine** such as OpenGL or Ogre. The advantage of this is that it can be easy to make a GUI for changing the camera viewpoint and other complex rendering effects can be added.
2. **Determine the model-to-image homography matrix** and render with OpenCV using `warpPerspective`. The advantage of this is that it can be done in a few lines without breaking into rendering software. The disadvantage is that you can get some strange effects if the homography has a vanishing point in the render (as you are observing). More on that point later.

### Definition of model-to-image homography

To use the OpenCV approach we define the *model-to-image* homography as **H**2. This can be defined in terms of the camera parameters. Consider a point **p**=(x,y,1) on the model plane in homogeneous coordinates. Its position **q** in I2 in homogeneous coordinates is given by **q**=**K M p**, where **M** is. 3x3 matrix given by **M**=(T00,T01,T03; T10,T11,T13; T20,T21,T23). This is straightforward to derive using the perspective camera model. Consequently, we now have that **H**2 =**K M**.

### Instantiate the homography matrix

Now we have to instantiate the homography, unlike your proposed approach, I would define it using a particular camera configuration, by specifying **K**, **R**1, **t**1, **R**2. The choice is up to you! To simplify the definition of **K** you can use a simple form with one free parameter (focal length), and set the  principal point to the image centre. For typical cameras f ranges between 0.5 and 2 time the image width, but it's up to you. You then need to set **R**1 and **t**1 depending on the viewing angle/distance that you want for your viewpoint.

### How is this different to your current approach

I want to emphasize that this does not contradict any of the previous answers I have given. It is simply a different approach which may be easier to manage. Essentially, here I am proposing to define your homography directly using camera parameters (which you set as you want). This guarantees you are using a sensible intrinsic matrix (because you set it yourself). It is different to your approach where you first create a homography and then want to find the matching camera parameters (which may or not be physically sensible).